# "Bash" vs. "party"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, slang

Our management team ask us to join a pizza/beer **bash**, which is essentially nothing but a pizza lunch held for all employees.

My concept of the word **bash** still remained somewhere near the name of the famous Unix shell until I looked it up online. As expected, a bash means a party or a celebration. It's a slang.

Anyway, I have a hard time distinguishing between **bash** and **party** from online resources. Maybe someone who themselves has been to both of them could tell the subtle difference.

Comment: Now I want to create a new Linux shell: `shindig`.

Comment: @WayneWerner I'd like to get involved in the shindig project once you start it :)

Comment: @WayneWerner `alias shindig=/usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: Bash, as in [WinterBash](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A ***bash*** is the same thing as a ***party*** in my experience.  The word *bash* is just a more colloquial or even slang way of saying party.  This is supported by [a dictionary definition of bash](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bash).

Comment: Yup. Pretty much just an alternate word to use.

Comment: In my mind, "bash" has a more riotous connotation, but it isn't always used that way. I think sometimes it is used to suggest that the party will be very enthusiastic.

Answer (score 7):

*Bash* is informal and indicates that the party is extremely exciting. It is a bit ironic when used in reference to an office party.

Comment: Ironic? Our last bash got out of hand because of the beer thing. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: YMMV, @TerryLiYifeng, I'm just going on past experience :)

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng I think the world would benefit from knowing where it is that you work such that office parties are considered exciting!

Comment: @CodeJockey Our headquarters is located in California while our office is embraced by GTA :)

Comment: @Code Jockey: But are their office parties considered exciting because they are so much better than other companies' office parties? Or are the considered exciting because the employees have such dull lives that they also consider getting new staplers to be exciting?

Comment: Or when used at a school-sponsered "6th grade bash" :P

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard a friend use the term bash to describe a gathering.  Bash just seems like a corporate term to describe a party.  Bash feels like it's trying too hard.  Bash is the word a parent would use to try to relate to his teenager.  Bash wears socks with sandals.

Answer (score 0):

"Bash" is, in my experience, most commonly used with "Birthday" or other b-words in the title of an event or invitation for an alliterative effect. You wouldn't use it in casual conversation as a generic term, unless a past bash somehow became proverbial: "Yeah, the office Flag Day Fest is going to be a real Bash of '97 this year."

Answer (score 0):

Although I understand that bash means party, it is not used in that way often in eastern Canada. My own connotation on it would be that a bash would be less formal or less organized than a party, however this could be regional.

Comment: As  a BrE speaker I understand _bash_ in pretty much the same way as you. I would say that _bash_ is a partial synonym of _party_ in that you can have very formal parties but not very formal bashes. Having said that I've heard some pretty plush events described as _bashes_.